# SQL Query Group by Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-server-2012

I am facing a problem with a `SQL` query. This is my table structure:

```
DECLARE @tab TABLE
             (
                   Id INT IDENTITY, 
                   Rid INT, 
                   Address1 VARCHAR(50),
                   City VARCHAR(20)
              ) 

INSERT INTO @tab VALUES (56, 'Test1', 'New York')
INSERT INTO @tab VALUES (1253, 'Test1', 'Delhi')
INSERT INTO @tab VALUES (56, 'Address5', 'Cali')
INSERT INTO @tab VALUES (1253, 'Address5', 'Delhi')

SELECT * FROM @tab
```

**My query:**

```
SELECT
    Address1, STUFF((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(Varchar, Id)
                     FROM @tab TR
                     WHERE TR.Rid IN (56, 1253)
                     GROUP BY Id, Rid, Address1 
                     FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS addid
FROM
    @tab T
WHERE 
    T.Rid IN (56,1253)
GROUP BY
    T.Address1
```

It is showing me all the Ids in comma wise, while I want to show the Ids `Address` wise like `1,2` in the first column and `3,4` in the second column, i.e. Ids should be group by Address1.

Thanks

Comment: The problem isn't your `GROUP BY` it's the lack of a lateral join in the `WHERE` of your subquery.

Comment: Please tell me the changes I need to make, I am unable to make out where to make changes in my query. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter `TR.Address1` = `T.Address1` instead of `TR.Rid IN (56, 1253)`

```
SELECT
    Address1, STUFF((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(Varchar, Id)
                     FROM @tab TR
                     WHERE TR.Address1 = T.Address1 // Adjust the condition here
                     GROUP BY Id, Rid, Address1 
                     FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS addid
FROM
    @tab T
WHERE 
    T.Rid IN (56,1253)
GROUP BY
    T.Address1
```

[Live demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ecfceeabdb0cbc6b6fdd6d1f371d2ed3)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need a correlated subquery.  I would suggest writing the query as:

```
SELECT Address1,
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(Varchar(MAX), Id)
              FROM tab TR
              WHERE TR.Address1 = T.Address1
              FOR XML PATH('')
             ), 1, 1, '') AS addid
FROM  tab T
WHERE T.Rid IN (56, 1253)
GROUP BY Address1
```

Notes:

- No aggregation is needed in the subquery.
- Do not use `varchar` without a length in SQL Server.  The length varies by context and it introduces hard-to-debug errors.
- The correlation clause is tying the values back to the values in the outer query -- based on the address.
- It is unclear whether or not year really need to filter on `T.Rid` in the subquery.  For your sample data, it is not necessary.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e6a206d3b92ef87394f3a88ddc5a9236) is a db<>fiddle.

In more recent versions of SQL Server, you would simply use `string_agg()` -- so you will be able to forget this XML hack.